# Maven not putting war file to correct folder

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, maven-war-plugin

Here an snippet pom.xml

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>C:/Users/Tom/Desktop</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

It creates the war file to my `target` folder inside eclipse workspace.
It should put the war folder to my desktop, but it only puts `WEB-INF, META-INF` folders there. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `outputDirectory` option, not the `webappDirectory`

see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html